# Is someone trying to hack me through facebook?

Tags: facebook, social-engineering, social-media

For the past few days i have been receiving friend requests in facebook from some hot girls that have some pictures of them in sexy poses and in the timeline it says they want to meet and have sex and it has a link to click. Those accounts all have the same location as i do but they have few friends (less than 10, but also in my location!).
The request only lasts like 1h or 2h, then the account is gone.

What's going on? Is someone trying to hack me? Is this just some automation that creates accounts in some region, and then targets people in that region so those people go to the link?

Comment: They are definitely going phishing.  You can restrict who posts on your Timeline, and I think even those who can send you friend requests.  Although I'm not sure on that last point.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is hacking per se.  It sounds more like spam.  Regardless, don't click on the link.  It's clear they are not real profiles, and there is no good that could come of it.

Comment: @user52472 I didn't click (had to resist beacuse i would like to troll them a bit). Is this type of facebook spam commom? What is the chance of this being specifically targeted at me?

Comment: you know what they say about "too good to be true"?

Comment: @power_output There's a chance that this attack is targeted at you, but it's unlikely. A smart attacker would try to fake an account that would be familiar to you (an old friend or family member). It's much more likely that your account just got put on a list someplace and they're spamming everyone.